# Google Tag Manager js widget tracking for multiple properties

Tags: javascript, widget, google-tag-manager

We are developing a widget that is implemented on multiple customer's websites as 3rd party element. On those websites the widget is only present on some of the sites. The widget uses Google Analytics for tracking everything that is happening there.

In the next step, we want to move from Google Analytics to Google Tag Manager. Many of the host sites we are implemented on already use Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager.

The requirement is to be able to distribute tracking data through the Google Tag Manager in a certain way:

1. We want to see all of the tracking information in our own Google Analytics property (this is pretty easy)
2. We want to send SOME of the data to the Google Analytics property our customers are using so they can view it in their own tracking.
3. We want to make sure that the tracking data the customer receives is not inconsistent with the tracking that is already going on. In other words: We need to avoid that users are counted twice and we want to make sure that a user that has taken a certain widget action can be viewed in the customers property with the entire browsing history (effectively inject widget activities in the regular tracking)
4. We don't want to pollute our own tracking by receiving a lot of data from the host site into our own property.

My initial idea how to do this (not sure if it will work):

- create another instance of google tag manager (namespaced)
- gather all widget events in our own tag manager
- create a lookup table to distribute the tracked data to different Google Analytics properties using the `hostname`as filter

So can you help me figuring out if this could work especially for (3.) and (4.) and how it should be architected?

Comment: What kind of data (I assume this would be event tracking rather than pageview tracking) do you intend to send ?

Comment: Hi @EikePierstorff you are right, everything that will be tracked are events. Currently we use virtual page views where it makes sense (the widget is built with react but without react router) but it could as well be events only.

Answer (score 0):

Being your GTM powered customer I'd definitely prefer your widget not to send data to my analytics but just send event pushes to `dataLayer` so I could configure and customize my tags firing. This would let to avoid data inconsistency in (.3) .
Using your own GTM container alongside customer's container could lead to some data pollution since both containers will use the same `dataLayer` in default configuration.
To keep your own data clean you can stick to default analytics.js implementation with your separate settings and only send data to your GA account.

Comment: also I had an experience of setting up tracking for 3d party widget CarrotQuest. That widget provided `addCallback()` API for key interaction events and so it was easy to set up my own tracking with pushing `dataLayer` events with callbacks

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Using our own GA account is what we currently have but it lacks the property in (3.) to provide data into the data layer of our customer (in order to show events in the customer's analytics that are related to the widget). Isn't there another way such as namespacing all the data coming from our GTM container so it could be filtered by both: Our GTM looking for the namespace and the customers GTM looking for non-namespaced elements?